# Affine image of the convex hull is its subset

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

For a set of points $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_r\in \mathbb R^n$ let's use $\mathcal P(v_1,\dots,v_r)$ to denote the convex hull of these points. Let us consider $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb R^n$ and denote
$$
f(\mathcal P) = \{Ax+b:x\in \mathcal P\}.
$$
Given $v_1,\dots, v_r$ I wonder about necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $A,b$ for
$$
f(\mathcal P) \subset \mathcal P.\tag{1}
$$
I am completely new to this area - just recently read the paper which considers the system
$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_k+b
$$ 
in $\mathcal P$ but there is no justification given on why should the dynamics always be inside $\mathcal P$. Of course, $(1)$ is a necessary and sufficient for that, but now I wonder how restrictive is condition $(1)$ on $A$ and $b$. Maybe the problem and solution are well-known - and please, feel free to retag.

Comment: Well, $Av_k+b\in\mathcal P$ for all $k$ is a necessary and sufficient condition, but I'd surprised if you find anything general and useful beyond. If you like, you can rephrase that as $b\in\bigcap_k(\mathcal P-Av_k)$.

Comment: @joriki: thanks - I was also expecting some necessary conditions on $A$ - say that the spectral radius $\rho(A)\leq 1$ to avoid expansions

Comment: In fact $|\det A|\le1$, since the volume is multiplied by $|\det A|$ and must fit into the original volume. Both of those bounds are obviously tight since $A$ can be the identity.